# How to make Javascript load on pageload

Tags: javascript, jira

I want to make this JS function go from a button to a page load

I am integrating a jira issue collector into our webpage.

```
<a href="#" id="myCustomTrigger">Bug Report</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
"triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
//Requires that jQuery is available! 
jQuery("#myCustomTrigger").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
showCollectorDialog();
});
}};</script>
```

To load when the page reloads I used the  window.onload but that didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a document complete jquery handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
      showCollectorDialog();
});
```

This will run as soon as the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Sorry where do I place that exactly?

Comment: You can also use plain JavaScript: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCollectorDialog);`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch and that goes above or below my code snippet?

Comment: below, as the last bit of script on the page

Answer (score 2):

here you can do it it with jquery just like like this.You can place this at the end of your html file.And also include jquery cdn in script tags in your html file.

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
  alert('hello world');
});​
```

or you can do this like this

```
function functionName() {
    alert('hello world');
}

window.onload = functionName;
```

Comment: Do i get rid of the jquery part or put all that code inside of the document.ready function?

Comment: put all your function inside $(document).ready(function(){ your function here})

Comment: Like this 

<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
"triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
//Requires that jQuery is available! 
jQuery("#myCustomTrigger").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
showCollectorDialog();
});
}};
});</script>

Answer (score 1):

Looking for an easy answer, nothing works from existing googles.

No custom triggers needed.
Put this into your html head and it will trigger the form, I just tested it ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {

$('#atlwdg-trigger').trigger('click');

},100);
</script>
```